# Let $P(A)=P(B)=0.42$ and $P(A∩B)=0.13$. Find $P(A'∪B')$

Tags: probability

> Let $P(A)=P(B)=0.42$ and $P(A∩B)=0.13$. Find $P(A'∪B')$.

Solution

$P(A'∪B')=P(A)+P(B)-P(A∩B)=0.42+0.42-0.13=0.71$.

Is it correct?

Comment: So you are claiming P(not A or not B) is the same as P(A or  B)?

Comment: but when I draw van diagram it gives me the same

Comment: P( not A or not B) contains everything outside the two intersecting circles and with in the universal set or a "rectangle" surrounding your circles, while P(A)+P(B)-P(A and B) contains everything inside the two circles. Because P( not A or not B) is outside the borders of the shape  A or B formed by the intersecting circles, they cannot be the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

I assume that by $'$ you mean the complement.

We have
$$P(A'\cup B') = 1-P[(A'\cup B')'] = 1-P(A\cap B) = 1-.13 = .87$$

where the second equality is true by DeMorgan's law.

Otherwise, you should get
$$P(A'\cup B') = P(A')+P(B')-P(A'B')$$
by inclusion-exclusion.